# Как получить все запросы в инспекторе, если есть перенаправления?

Tags: редирект

Как получить все запросы в инспекторе Chrome, если есть перенаправления? После редиректа стираются предыдущие записи.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

включите галочку **Preserve log**.